# Move Windows 8.1 to other hardrive on dual boot system

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, windows-10, boot-manager

I am trying to move my windows 8.1 OS partition to a second HDD. I will try to explain what I have tried so far.

I started with a Windows 8.1 installation on a SSD (120GB). I have also an HDD of 500GB in the laptop that I used for data. Then I installed Windows 10 in Dual Boot on the SSD which worked fine. However, the SSD was to small for both OS's, so I tried to copy my Windows 8.1 partition to the HDD. And added the new partition tot the bootmanager (bootrec /rebuildbcd). When I try to boot the new OS entry in the bootmanager, the startup repair automatically starts up and shows a message that it was unable to repair the startup.

Then I tried to migrate the Windows 8.1 partition to the HDD by using the migrate HDD/SSD option of EaseUS partition master, which copied both the system partition and Windows 8.1 OS partition to the HDD. Then I ran bootrec /rebuildbcd again, but with the same results.

I have no idea what to try next. Has anyone a suggestion on what I can try now?

Comment: Backup to 3rd drive, remove original drive, restore to new drive.

Comment: I dont want to change my drive, I want to leave the SSD as my primary drive (disk 0) and just move my windows 8.1 from disk 0 to disk 1 (HDD). And leave the system as a dualboot with windows 10 on the SSD. Or do you mean that I should make a windows image backup from windows 8.1 and restore it to disk 1? Will that leave the windows 10 intact?

Comment: I tried it using the Windows system image backup, but when I try to restore the image, WINRE wants to format the SSD instead of the HDD.